# Custom responsive 'featured image' sizes

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, responsive

My home page has a carousel of 'featured (thumbnail) images' from posts. The carousel uses about two=thirds of the screen width and Google Page Speed Analyser complains that my images are too large.

What I would like to insert into my bootstrap carousel code would be something like:

```
<img src="//localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/Oysters-at-A-fusion.jpg" 
class="attachment-front_page_lg size-front_page_lg wp-post-image" alt="Oysters at A-fusion" 
srcset="//localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/Oysters-at-A-fusion-525x270.jpg 525w, //localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/Oysters-at-A-fusion-420x320.jpg 420w" 
sizes="66vw" />
```

I'm not completely sure about the sizes element.

<strike>I'm trying to address that by declaring custom image sizes</strike>

```
/* Image Sizes  
    Large : 525 x 270
    iPhone6 210 * 180   and then 2x that?
*/
add_image_size( "card", 400, 400, false );
add_image_size( "front_page_sm", 420, 360, true );
add_image_size( "front_page_lg", 520, 270, true );
```

My first problem is that however often I run regenerate thumbnails I do not get these sizes (although I do see images of size 400, which I use elsewhere).

The image regeneration suddenly started working! The following code creates the img tag

```
function getFeaturedImage($resto) {
    global $table_prefix;
    global $wpdb;
    $query = "...";
    $queryResult = $wpdb->get_results($query);
    $post_id = $queryResult[0]->post_id;
    return get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'front_page_lg');
}
```

This does get the $post_id correctly, but results in

```
<img width="405" height="270" 
src="//localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Restaurant-Breda-Amsterdam-1.jpg" 
class="attachment-front_page_lg size-front_page_lg wp-post-image"
alt="restaurant-breda-amsterdam-1" />
```

This is a real problem as it is using the original (large) version of the image.

However, and in some cases I get

```
<img width="270" height="270" 
src="//localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/Oysters-at-A-fusion.jpg" 
class="attachment-front_page_lg size-front_page_lg wp-post-image" alt="Oysters at A-fusion" 
srcset="//localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/Oysters-at-A-fusion.jpg 768w, //localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/Oysters-at-A-fusion-150x150.jpg 150w, //localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/Oysters-at-A-fusion-500x500.jpg 500w, //localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/Oysters-at-A-fusion-400x400.jpg 400w" 
sizes="(max-width: 270px) 100vw, 270px" />
```

Clearly this srcset is going to be valuable to me and - as far as I know - is being generated by wordpress rather than a plugin. But it only happens for a few posts and with unuseful sizes.

**How can I get a src set with my two custom sizes?**

Answer (score 2):

First off, I'm not really sure why you need to involve the `wpdb` class just to create the img tag. If you want to get the featured image, you can use the Wordpress functions [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/)  and [`the_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/)which both allow you to specify the registered size you want, and return the markup like so:

```
// In the loop:
the_post_thumbnail( 'front_page_lg' ); // echos the markup

// Outside the loop:
$img_markup = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'front_page_lg' );
```

From there, you have two different hooks to customize that markup:

- [`wp_calculate_image_srcset`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_calculate_image_srcset/) filter
- [`wp_calculate_image_sizes`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_calculate_image_sizes/) filter

Here's an example of using `wp_calculate_image_srcset`:

```
function wpse_custom_image_srcset( $sources, $size_array, $image_src, $image_meta, $attachment_id ){
    $w = 768; // setup a custom width here, repeat below for as many custom widths as you want, linking to your URL
    $sources[$w] = array(
        'url'  => 'myfolder/myimage.jpg',
        'descriptor' => 'w',
        'value'      => $w,
    );
    return $sources;
}
add_filter( 'wp_calculate_image_srcset', 'wpse_custom_image_srcset', 10, 5 );
```

and here's an example of using `wp_calculate_image_sizes`:

```
function wpse_post_thumbnail_sizes_attr( $attr, $attachment, $size ) {
    //Calculate Image Sizes by type and breakpoint
    if ($size === 'front_page_lg') {
        $attr['sizes'] = '(max-width: 768px) 92vw, (max-width: 992px) 450px, (max-width: 1200px) 597px, 730px';
    }  
    return $attr;
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'wpse_post_thumbnail_sizes_attr', 10 , 3 );
```

This *should* give you a headstart, but obviously you'll have to tweak these until you're getting the markup you're looking for with your custom image sizes and breakpoints. Here's some more resources which should help:

- https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/11/10/responsive-images-in-wordpress-4-4/
- https://viastudio.com/optimizing-your-theme-for-wordpress-4-4s-responsive-images/